# Generate all possible heads up matchups from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to find the performant way to create match-ups for players in an array and return all possible match-ups for all players in a multidimensional array without duplicating any match-ups.

Here is my example:

```
// input
var players = [
  {player: 'sam' }, {player: 'bob' }, {player: 'tim' }, {player: 'kevin' }
];

// output
var mathups = [
  [{player: 'sam'},  {player: 'bob}],  
  [{player: 'sam'},  {player: 'tim'}], 
  [{player: 'sam'},  {player: 'kevin'}],
  [{player: 'bob'},  {player: 'tim'}],  
  [{player: 'bob'},  {player: 'kevin'}]
  ... and so on
];
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this with vanilla JS or using something like lodash or underscore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combinations can be generated like this without an external lib:

```js
var players = [
  {player: 'sam' }, {player: 'bob' }, {player: 'tim' }, {player: 'kevin' }
];


var m = [];

for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i+1; j < players.length; j++) {
    m.push([players[i], players[j]]);
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(m,null, 2));
```

Comment: so sick. this is a ton easier than I could imagine.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, assuming there is duplicates in the name.

```
var players = [{
    player: 'sam'
}, {
    player: 'bob'
}, {
    player: 'tim'
}, {
    player: 'kevin'
}];

function makeMatch()
{

    var matchList = [];

    for (var i=0; i<players.length; i++)
    {
        for (var j=i+1; j<players.length; j++)
        {
            matchList.push([{player: players[i].player}, {player: players[j].player}]);
        }
    }

    console.log(matchList);
}

makeMatch();
```